# meridian convergence local coordinate systems

Tags: coordinate-system, convergence, true-north, grid-north

I am new to the concept of meridian convergence. I understand that it is the angle between True North and Grid North. But I have problems understanding how 
 meridian convergence affects local Coordinate Reference System (CRS), such as the Gauss-Krüger system?

[image]